# Aero Glass/Transparent window borders in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, aero, transparency

While I'm really liking **Windows 8**, I do miss having the semi-transparent borders round my windows, like with Aero Glass in Windows 7.

I note that the taskbar in Windows 8 is semi-transparent...

[image]

Is there a way to change windows border opacity, to restore Aero Glass or even just so that it looks like the taskbar?

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Aero Glass** can be enabled with a DLL available for free [here](http://glass8.eu/):

[image: Reimplemented Windows Blur effect]

This DLL is loaded via AppInit into the DWM.exe and Explorer.exe and and hooks the functions `SetWindowCompositionAttribute` and `DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow` and implements them again to enable the Glass effect again in Windows 8.

Now you can work with Windows 8 without getting headache because of the ugly Theme :)

Comment: Nice! I'd certainly like to see that. It's still in Beta and apparently has warning boxes that appear periodically to remind. When it's finished, I'll check it out! http://glass8.berlios.de/

Comment: Ah, I've got some freebie reputation points, so I can now comment instead of editing. The link you provided does not explain clearly what to do with this DLL (I failed to make it work following instructions), so I changed it to installer link. Please consider to review your answer and provide correct instructions on how to install it correctly.

Comment: don't link to **UNOFFICIAL** installers. The readme.txt explains how to use it. If you can't follow the steps, don't use the DLL!

Comment: @Django Reinhardt the DLL is now finished and Version 1.0 is released. donate a few bucks to get a license key.

Comment: The link is dead =/

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy I fixed the link.

Comment: I have the "Your DWM is incompatible" messages. How do you let Aero Glass to know location of required function inside DLL?

Comment: I did this `set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=srv*DownstreamStore*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` from a cmd prompt as I do not know I should set it to force aerohost.exe to load relevant symbols from microsoft.

Comment: I set `_NT_SYMBOL_PATH` environment variable to `srv*DownstreamStore*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` and reinstall aero glass. My current build of windows 10 is supported by aero glass but is still show the DWM incompatible issues.

Comment: @yoonghm set it to `srv*C:\AeroGlass\Symbols*` so Symbols folder inside your AeroGlass folder

Answer (score 16):

Not really. Windows no longer adds transparency to their windows. Therefore, officially there is no way to do it. You could try this guide:

http://www.intowindows.com/enable-aero-glass-in-windows-8/

However, I am not sure if that works in the latest build. There also might be some third party apps, I'll try to find one after I'm done writing. Good luck.

EDIT:

Alright, you can look at this third party app as well. I can not vouch for it's security though. I have never tried it. Here is an article showing it off.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/aero8tuner-get-a-hint-of-the-old-aero-glass-effect-back-in-windows-8/