# Is it possible to get transparency on title bars in Windows 8, like Aero of Windows 7?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aero Glass/Transparent window borders in Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/q/489853/138020)

Is it possible to get transparency on title bars in Windows 8, like Aero was in Windows 7? My Chrome title bar is feeling super bright compared to Windows 7.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is no longer officially supported. However, there are some applications which can bring back the aero look.

You can use:

- [Registry hacks](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWt94nGwzZ4) (buggy, and not recommended)
- [Aero8Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.95) (might also have bugs when moving transparent windows - I am not sure)

Sources:

- http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-enable-and-customize-aero-glass-in-windows-8-video/
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jWt94nGwzZ4

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the chrome bar being to bright you can change the themes from the [chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes)